# Why use Sparksql to query elasticsesarch the result incorrect

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I'm using `sparkSql` to query `elasticsearch`. The program runs successfully, but the query result incorrect. The SQL is:

```
 select count(1) from myTableName;
```

Every time run the program the result is nonconformity. How can I guarantee the result is the same?